# What happens when you connect an Android phone to another Android phone?

Tags: samsung, file-transfer, htc, data-transfer

I've just connected my HTC Butterfly to a Galaxy Note 3 (micro-USB to female USB -> Male USB to micro-USB)...

And nothing really happened. What is supposed to happen? Am I able to view the other phones' storage, and vica versa? It did say something regarding keyboard(s), assuming it thought it was a keyboard?

I've been doing a couple of tests, using file manager, trying to transfer files, play music, etc... But nothing seems to work.

Is it possible to transfer files like that? (Not that it's handy; I just want to know if it's possible.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to transfer using an [OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) cable. But you require at least one of the phones to support OTG, and it is better explained [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2640456). The phones mentioned in the post are Xperia and Micromax. I am sure it will work with the rest of the OTG-supported phones too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be experimenting a lot, trying to charge other phones etc with this. Pretty amazing in my opinion. Thank you again!